# Comment other comments in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a model for comments which uses `GenericForeignKey` and a model for posts.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    text = models.TextField()
    comments = generic.GenericRelation('self')

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)
```

I can get all comments belonging to a post in templates with

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I need to comment other comments.

I can get 'next level' of comments with

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment }}

    {% for sub_comment in comment.comments.all %}
        {{ sub_comment }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way I can only get a specified number of levels.

How can I traverse all comments belonging to the post or belonging to other comments which are belonging to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I smell Tree structure here.
For this in Django you can use: [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)

It adds several columns to your table and [a lot usefull stuff](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html) to work with your model as a tree structure.

And it claims to be very efficient

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly add a function to the models module that traverses the comment tree and yields each comment in order, like so:

```
# Note this will work given either a Post or Comment object
def traverse_comment_tree(obj_with_comments):
    for comment in obj_with_comments.comments.all():
        yield comment
        for descendant_comment in traverse_comment_tree(c):
            yield descendant_comment

class Post(models.Model):
    [...]
    def all_comments(self):
        return (c for c in traverse_comment_tree(self))
```

As an aside, note that `traverse_comment_tree` is basically a [pre-order depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first) (with a `Post` object as the tree root, so it is never "visited" as only `Comment` objects are desired).

Then the template would work like this:

```
{% for comment in post.all_comments %}
    {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

All comments should then be traversed and output in the proper order (i.e. *all* descendants of one top-level comment are output before the next top-level comment). The next step would be to implement a way for the template to know which "level" of comment it is on.

This method, with a QuerySet call per comment, is inefficient of course; but hopefully it will help steer you in the right direction.